# Matlab and Cauchy's Argument Principle: Plot the contour on the s-plane of a transfer Function

Tags: laplace-transform, matlab

### **Questions**

**1. How do I plot the contour of a given Nyquist plot onto the *s-plane of a given transfer function on Matlab?**

*s-plane: is the complex plane on which Laplace transforms are graphed. It Has imaginary(vertical) and real(horizontal) axis.

---

**2. How do I plot a function like of that of a parabola shape onto the s-plane(on Matlab but also in general).**

**2a. What is then the mathematical function look like?**

---

### Explanation of Cauchy's Argument Principle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sof3meN96MA
Time code: ***4:03*** for explanation

---

I want to compare the plot to its contour s-plane counter part.

This will help better visualize the relationship between a Nyquist plot and it's benefits of using its representation.

---

I could not find anything on the Matlab Nyquist function page:
Nyquist Matlab Function: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nyquist.html

Comment: With a given Nyquist plot you mean using a contour which might be different from $s=j\,\omega$ with $-\infty<\omega<\infty$?

Comment: Yes. I mean using Cauchy's Argument Principle in general. With going back from the plot in the F(s)-plane back to the contour in the s-plane